# How to replace part of a text using regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am fetching HTML content from database and displaying in UI. If the displayed content contains images having width and height specified then I need to replace the image width and height to some fixed value while displaying in UI.

One sample content is like:

```
<p>
   Sample paragraph text. 
   <br />
   <img src="http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg?width=500&height=500" 
    title="Test Image" />
   Sample text.
   <br />
</p>
```

Here, I want to set the image **width=300** and remove the **height** dynamically for different images.

I have tried to replace the text using regular expression as follows:

```
.replace(new RegExp("width=([^&]{0,})", 'gi'), 'width=300') 
.replace(new RegExp("[?&]height=([^&]{0,})", 'gi'), '')
```

But it gives result as follows:

```
<p>Sample paragraph text. <br /> <img src="http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg?width=300
```

It replaces all the text after **?width=300**.

I want the result like:
     `<p>Sample paragraph text. 
<br /> <img src="http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg?width=300" title="Test Image" /> Sample text.<br /></p>`

So, I guess, the problem is in the regular expression.
Please help me to correct this.

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Parse the HTML first and only apply the string substitution on the attribute value you want to change (I assume you know how to traverse the DOM).

Comment: The browser parses the HTML, why not set innerHTML and then change the image dimensions ?

Comment: Why don't you try exact regex match `/^width=([^&]{0,})$/`

Comment: @Dystroy: I am using ImageResizer to set the image width and height. ImageResizer handles the width and height if it is specified in image "src" attribute. http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern: `/[^&]{0,}/` is gobbling up everything that is not a & character, which is why it extends beyond the URL itself. Instead, since you know that the width and height are numbers, you can just match on digits:

```
.replace(/\bwidth=\d*/gi,'width=300')
.replace(/&height=\d*|\bheight=\d*&?/gi,'');
```

The `\b` is a zero-width match to a word boundary, so that if you have framewidth=500 for example it won't be affected. The 2 matches to height are so that it won't replace both &'s if they are on each side. E.g. you don't want '?width=500&height=500&cache=123' to turn into '?width=300cache=123' for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more parameters in the query, this should do it:

```
.replace(/(\?width=)[^"]+/i, '$1300');
```

Put this in a console to test it:

```
"http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg?width=500&height=500".replace(/(\?width=)[^"]+/i, '$1300');
```